# picturebox.image saving overwrite in c#

Tags: c#, image, messagebox, overwrite

i have a project with a picturebox that by clicking on a button , i save picturebox.image , in a folder with "scan" name .
and if i insert an image with repetitive name in picturebox , when i save image , program overwrite the image in the folder .
but i want when i insert a same name image to the folder "scan" , i use a messagebox with message : " name of image is repetetive . please change the name of image " . help me please ..
here is my saving code :

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\scan\\ " + txtDesc11.Text + ".jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the file currently exists before you save. I encourage you, instead of just asking us to solve your problem you instead search "How do i check if a file exists?" and then try to solve the problem yourself.

```
string filePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\scan\\ " + txtDesc11.Text + ".jpg";
if (File.Exists(filepath)) 
{
    // show a message to the user
}
else
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(filePath);
}
```